# Subtracting rolling mean from pandas without for loop with unevenly sampled data and no datetime

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a column `DAY`, and a column `VALUE`. I would like to create a new column, `VALUE_SUB` which is made by subtracting a rolling window mean with width N of `VALUE` which rolls over `DAY` from `VALUE`. So, I have a dataframe like this:

```
DAY,   VALUE
1      8
2      6
4      7
5      6
8      10
10     8
```

And I want to subtract with a rolling mean of width 3 to get:

```
DAY,   VALUE,   VALUE_SUB
1      8        1
2      6        -1
4      7        0.5
5      6        -0.5
8      10       1
9      8        0.33
10     5        -1.5
```

I can do this with the following code:

```
out = []
for i in range(len(list(df['DAY']))):
    df1 = df[(df['DAY'] >= df['DAY'].iloc[i] - 1) & (df['DAY'] <= df['DAY'].iloc[i] + 1)]
    out += [df['VALUE'].iloc[i] - df1['VALUE'].mean()]
df['VALUE_SUB'] = out
```

But my dataframe is very large so this takes forever. I would like to do it without using a for loop at all, if possible. I know pandas has a rolling mean function that works for datetime objects or for rolling over a set number of rows, but my data does not have datetime objects nor is the data evenly sampled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the DAY column to a datetime object with `pd.to_datetim`e and set as the index to be able to use the `rolling.mean` with a centered window. keep only the values (to avoid mismatch on the index) and substract from the VALUE column.

```
# input
df = pd.DataFrame({'DAY': [1, 2, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10], 'VALUE': [8, 6, 7, 6, 10, 8, 5]})

n_day = 3
df['VALUE_SUB'] = (
    df['VALUE'] 
    - df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['DAY'], unit='d'))
        ['VALUE'].rolling(f'{n_day}d', center=True).mean().to_numpy()
)
print(df)
#    DAY  VALUE  VALUE_SUB
# 0    1      8   1.000000
# 1    2      6  -1.000000
# 2    4      7   0.500000
# 3    5      6  -0.500000
# 4    8     10   1.000000
# 5    9      8   0.333333
# 6   10      5  -1.500000
```

Comment: Thanks! The dataset I'm trying to analyze is of course much larger and more complex than the example I shared, so when I try your solution I get the following error: 'NotImplementedError: center is not implemented for datetimelike and offset based windows' -- do you know why that might be?

Comment: @Billiam probably a version difference in pandas. Apparently I'm using 1.3.3, I guess I did not updated it for a while on my side. Please try the method without the parameter `center=True` and see if it works (I know wrong result but just to see if you can run the code like this)